# The norm in the n-simplex

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology, normed-spaces, simplex, simplicial-complex

İ have this question and my attempt to solve it as the following :

> Consider an n-simplex $[p_0, p_1,...,p_n]$. If $a,b \in [p_0,
> > p_1,...,p_n]$, then show that $||a − b|| \leq \sup_i ||a − p_i||$.

**My attempt :**
since $b \in [p_0,p_1,...,p_n]$ then $b = \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i p_i$

where $t_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i = 1$.

Then using the equation
\begin{align}
||a − b| &= ||(\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i)a − $\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i p_i|| \\
         &= ||\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i (a-p_i)|| \\
    &\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i ||a-p_i|| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i \sum_{i=0}^{n} ||a-p_i||
\end{align}

but $\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i = 1$ so we have

$$||a − b| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} ||a-p_i||$$

but I don't know how I can complete , any help please!

Answer (score 1):

You got very close! You showed the first inequality in this chain.
\begin{align}
    ||a-b|| &\leq \sum_{i=0}^n t_i ||a-p_i|| \\
    & \leq \sum_{i=0}^n t_i \left (\sup_j ||a-p_j|| \right ) \\
    &= \sup_j ||a-p_j||= \sup_i ||a-p_i||
\end{align}
In the second line we have used the bound, valid for all $i=0,1,...,n$
$$||a-p_i|| \leq \sup_j ||a - p_j||$$
to upper bound each term in the second sum. The third line is just $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i = 1$.

Comment: thank you but why you use j instead of  i

Comment: I just wanted to avoid overloading the $i$ variable in both the supremum and the summation. You can always re-index. I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: but I can use i right ?

Comment: Yes, changing the index variable is always allowed.

Comment: but in the third line when we distribute the summation we get the sum of sup not sup right ?

Comment: It's a *weighted* sum of sup with weights $t_i$ which sum to 1. 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n t_i (\sup_j ||a-p_j||) = (\sup_j ||a-p_j||) \sum_{i=0}^n t_i = (\sup_j ||a-p_j||)(1)$$
Where the sup moves outside the sum because it doesn't depend on $i$.